# using ui param value and liter in EL ternary

Tags: el

I'm getting a EL parsing error when using literal and ui param value in ternary expression.  The parsing error occurs when the ternary condition is false (:'width:'width';').  Is there a way to get around this problem.  (Note: width is a ui:param name).

```
<fieldset style="#{(empty width)? '' :'width:'width';'}; class="standardSectionTemplate">
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not concatenate Strings like this in `EL`, unless you are using `EL 3.0`, 
In previous `EL` versions you can call concatenate method of each string.

Like this

```
style="#{ empty width ? '' : 'width:'.concat(width).concat(';') }"
```

In [`EL 3.0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el005.htm), you can do it like this

```
style="#{ empty width ? '' : 'width:' += width += ';' }"
```

Comment: getting null pointer error when using concat:  

    java.lang.NullPointerException
 javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:225)
 javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:225)
 org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
 org.apache.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:46)
 org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
 com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:217)
 com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:157)